# "Dependency is not satisfiable:lsb core (>=3.0)" while downloading Hamachi

Tags: server, software-center, 16.04

Hello I'm using Ubuntu MATE 16.04. I have a problem. I want to play Minecraft with my friends on our server. I own the server. We will connect by using hamachi. I downloaded Haguichi but it needs Hamachi.I downloaded the ".deb" file,I don't know how to open other files like **".rpm"** or **".tgz"**. I opened it with Ubuntu Software Center and it said **"Dependency is not satisfiable:lsb core (>=3.0)".**

How do I fix it ? Also I looked other satisfiable errors but I'm not sure if it works for me.

Comment: Open a terminal and do `sudo apt-get install lsb-core`. Then try to install the .deb file again. And please understand that this is a site run by volunteers. We have no guaranteed response times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note that this answer only works for 15.10 and earlier.**

When installing from a .deb file, dependencies do not get automatically installed as well, as would be the case if Hamachi were a complete package.

However, it is easy to install the dependency yourself in this case. Open a terminal and do

`sudo apt-get install lsb-core`

Then retry installing from the .deb file.

Comment: This answer only works for 15.10 and earlier.  Please refer to my answer if you are on 16.04 or newer.

Answer (score 1):

The [Hamachi download page](http://vpn.net/linux) states that "Note: The Linux client can now be installed without LSB package.", therefore it appears that the dependency on `lsb-core` has been dropped. Download the .deb file for Hamachi again and install it using `sudo dpkg -i`.

Answer (score 0):

> **Note that this answer only applies for Ubuntu 16.04 and newer!**

As of Ubuntu Xenial 16.04, most of the LSB tools and packages have been removed except for `lsb-base` and `lsb-release`.  As such, `lsb-core` and the rest of the packages from the `lsb` source package do not exist (the other two do.

The removal reason is documented in the package's NEWS entry from Debian, where the removal of LSB compatibility actually happened:

> ```
> lsb (9.20150826) unstable; urgency=low
>
>   This update drops all lsb-* compatibility packages, and is therefore an
>   abandon of the pursuit of LSB compatibility for Debian. Only lsb-release and
>   lsb-base are kept as they continue to be used throughout the archive.
>
>  -- Didier Raboud <odyx@debian.org>  Wed, 26 Aug 2015 12:00:00 +0200
> ```

There is no way to work around this removal, unfortunately, and one would have to reach out to Hamachi to retool their package to work around the lack of `lsb-core`.  There is, unfortunately, no way around this issue short of the creators of Hamachi updating their packaging.